# Being the first to provide a service in a Geographical Area

Tags: first, geographical

Quite new to patents. Is it possible to file one for a service that is the first to serve a certain geographical area? Say...a software-centric service.

To clarify, I want to patent locally something which is already done elsewhere in the world.

Comment: Each country has its own patent laws and courts so every patent application is an application to bar others from doing something particular within the territory the application is filed in. A granted UK patent only constraints what can be done in the U.K. Maybe I misunderstood the question. Were you asking if something old or ordinary can be made special by just doing it one specific location?

Comment: Exactly. Something already done elsewhere, but never done in a particular region or foreign country.

Comment: That is called "local novelty" vs absolute novelty. All significant countries require absolute novelty. Local novelty might be found in some small fairly closed countries. The first patent system (in Venice) awarded patents to first-to-import as well as first-to-invent but that was hundreds of years ago.